# binary heap to List

Tags: list, tree, prolog, append, binary-tree

Trying to append a tree structure into a list. In Erlang I would use the ++ operator for appending but I keep getting syntax errors when doing this in Prolog.

I will include my error code, its all about the appending of lists that I think is missing.

```
tree2list(leaf(X),L++[X]).
tree2list(branch(Branch1,Branch2),L):-
tree2List(B1,L1),
tree2List(B2,L2),
L++L1++L2.
```

Any ideas how to solve my appending issue?

Comment: There is no `++` operator in Prolog. Use `append/3`. Mind you, Prolog is only very superficially similar to Erlang; you'd better grab a good Prolog book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use difference lists:

```c
tree2list(leaf(X),[X|A]-A).
tree2list(branch(B1,B2),L-Z):-
        tree2list(B1,L-A),
        tree2list(B2,A-Z).

/* 7 ?- tree2list(branch(leaf(1),leaf(2)), L-[]).
L = [1, 2] ;
No
8 ?- */
```

But your tree doesn't seem to have empty branches. Add them thus:

```c
tree2list(empty,A-A).

/* 10 ?- tree2list(branch(branch(leaf(1),leaf(2)),empty), L-[]).
L = [1, 2] ;
No
11 ?- */
```

Comment: Agree on that my tree don't have empty branches, I haven't considered this so far. Any hints on how to handle this?

Comment: If I have a treestructure like branch(leaf(A),branch(leaf(AA),leaf(AAA)))

I get this as output 
L = [A, AA, AAA|_G6667]-_G6667 seems that the A reference "errors" to print out.

Comment: right, notice how I called it: `tree2list(...., L-[])`. This is probably over your head, if you're unfamiliar with Prolog, difference lists are not an entry material. Sorry for that.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the "_G6667]-_G6667" msg?

Comment: yes, call it this way: `tree2list(...., L-[])`. **Don't** call it as `tree2list(...., L)`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, to learn about this should I read up on the area "Difference lists" or do you recommend any other reading for deeper understanding?

Comment: Standard references can be found somewhere on SO in previous questions. I like Sterling and Shapiro; Bratko is very clear. Prolog is different, you really should invest in assimilating the basics properly. Although ultimately it  becomes clear and easy too. It's really about named *set-once* pointers. And backtracking.